# Can I be banned for running HEAD requests?

Tags: http, web-crawler

I have a specific idea that relies on running HEAD requests on a few third party URLs on a daily basis. As a reminder, this type of request does not download the content (body) of the webpage and is fairly lightweight. My goal is simply to assess if the URL is still available.

I would like to know if this could possibly be forbidden by the third party website? In my opinion, it should not since I won't be downloading any content. The only information that I am after is to know whether the URL is still valid or not.

Thanks!

Comment: Certainly it is possible to block such requests, question is if anyone will bother. That might be the case if the requests are a thread to the third parties business interests, of course. As always in such cases: _you should ask them..._